# Проблема с jquery.maphilight.js

Tags: html, jquery, css, изображения

Привет. Есть div, в нем изображение с разрешением: 1722х456. Также есть карта этого изображения. Грубо говоря:

```
<div id="container">
     <img id="image" usemap="Map">
</div>
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area с какими-то координатами>
    <area с какими-то координатами>
    <area с какими-то координатами>
</map>
```

В данном случае если подсветить изображение с помощью maphilight(), то области изображения без проблем подсвечиваются. Но, если div'у задать следующие стиль:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1480px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 55px;
}
```

А изображению этот:

```
#image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Т.к. у меня разрешение экрана 1366х768, то изображение уменьшается, т.е. подстраивается под экран. Чтобы скорректировать координаты карты изображений связи с уменьшением самого изображения я делаю следующее:

```
$('area').each(function() {
    var img = document.getElementById('image');
    var height = img.clientHeight;

    var orig_coords = $(this).attr('orig-coords');
    if (!orig_coords) {
        orig_coords = $(this).attr('coords');
        $(this).attr('orig-coords', orig_coords);
    }
    var scale = height / 456;
    $(this).attr('coords', orig_coords.split(',').map(function(x) {
        return Math.round(x * scale)
    }).join(','));
});
```

Теперь изображение уменьшено (влезло в экран) и координаты карты скорректированы. Но, если я попытаюсь подсветить изображение снова с maphilight(), то изображение остается с оригинальным разрешением, карта изображения не работает и, следовательно, зоны карты не подсвечиваются. 
Вопрос: в чём проблема? 8(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После долгих мучений все-таки нашел [решение](https://github.com/kemayo/maphilight/issues/21)